# How to add a POS tag layer to a Keras model?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I have an LSTM model which currently looks like the following:

```
model = tf.keras.Sequential([
    encoder,
    tf.keras.layers.Embedding(input_dim=len(encoder.get_vocabulary()), output_dim=64, mask_zero=True),
    tf.keras.layers.Bidirectional(tf.keras.layers.LSTM(64)),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(64, activation='relu'),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(len(encoded_lbls), activation='softmax')
])
```

And I want to add a layer before the `encoder`, to convert the text to part of speech tags (POS). The text is already tokenized, and I can use `nltk` to POSify it:

```
def posify_data(txt):
    return ' '.join([pair[1] for pair in nltk.pos_tag(txt.split())])

posify_data('the quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog')

# Output:
# DT JJ NN NN VBZ IN DT JJ NN
```

How do I add this function as a layer? I tried to add the following line before `encoder`:

`tf.keras.layers.Lambda(posify_data),`

But I'm getting an error:

> 'Tensor' object has no attribute 'split'

Answer (score 0):

You can create the POS tagging in the preprocessing phase and insert them as additional input to the model.
The layer doesn't have any parameters to train therefore it will not lead to any impairment of the model performance.

Link to example:
[Part-of-Speech tagging tutorial with the Keras Deep Learning library](https://becominghuman.ai/part-of-speech-tagging-tutorial-with-the-keras-deep-learning-library-d7f93fa05537)